# Does export in schema mode also includes tablespaces?

Tags: oracle, schema, import, export, tablespaces

I am executing an expdp command in schema mode. I'm just curious if it also exports tablespaces. I'm total newbie in oracle databases. What if I want to export schemas and tablespaces? What mode do I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:
"Full Export Mode

A full export is specified using the FULL parameter. In a full database export, the entire database is unloaded."

FULL=YES indicates that all data and metadata are to be exported.

Restrictions

```
A full export does not export system schemas that contain Oracle-managed data and metadata. Examples of system schemas that are not exported include SYS, ORDSYS, and MDSYS.

Grants on objects owned by the SYS schema are never exported.
```

It's all spelled out pretty clearly in the Utilities manual.  For 11g, that's at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL825

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#i1007519

> Tablespace Mode
>
> A tablespace export is specified using the TABLESPACES
> parameter. In tablespace mode, only the tables contained in a
> specified set of tablespaces are unloaded. If a table is unloaded,
> then its dependent objects are also unloaded. Both object metadata and
> data are unloaded. In tablespace mode, if any part of a table resides
> in the specified set, then that table and all of its dependent objects
> are exported.

e.g.

```
expdp hr DIRECTORY=pump DUMPFILE=tbs456.dmp TABLESPACES=tbs_4, tbs_5, tbs_6
```

Comment: What if I use export in full mode? Does it include all the exporting modes? Does it take so much time to process?